# Windows 7 DVD doesn't boot up, neither does USB. 

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, multi-boot

My problem is that I'm not able to install windows 7. Been trying to install this since past 1 week. The methods I've tried are:

1. I have a windows 7 bootable DVD which doesn't boot up. (I've set BIOS to boot from DVD ROM first but it just won't boot from the DVD).
   Tried to install Windows 7 from the same DVD to a friend's PC and it worked. So the DVD has no issues.
2. I tried to run 'Setup.exe' from within the DVD. The two options pop-up 'Check compatibility' and 'Install now'. On clicking install now, after sometime, an error is encountered with the message 'Windows was unable to create a required installation folder' error code:0x8007000D.
   I am running Windows XP Professional and there's only one user on the PC which is the Admin, so I do not know why is the setup not getting permissions. I've also uninstalled my antivirus, CD burning software, disabled firewall and disconnected all other devices, but its still the same.
3. I tried to install it from a USB device by making it bootable but that too doesnt work. (Yes the motherboard supports booting from the USB).
   The problem is that XP does not recognize a 'USB' device on boot. Rather it shows this USB stick as a removable 'Hard Drive'. Furthermore, i changed the order of Hard Drive boot to boot from this removable Hard Drive first, it still boots my existing OS.

Is there anything else that can be done? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please ask if any other information is required, this post is becoming increasingly long to add any other details.

PS: I want to dual boot windows 7 with my existing XP, but that would be after i manage to run the windows 7 setup in the first place.

PPS: Please bare with any 'not-so-technical' terms, I am a beginner with this.  Again, thank you for taking the time and trying to help, really appreciate it.

Comment: What computer are you using?

Comment: Compaq desktop PC with 2GB RAM (Two 1 GB memory modules). Pentium dual core processor 2.0 GHz, Intel motherboard.

Comment: Try pressing F10 when you reboot, before the windows logo appears, and see if the DVD or USB is detected

Answer (score 0):

The error may be related to [a problem with a camera, scanner or other device](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/error-code-0x8007000d-t3008725.html) that's connected to your machine.  Unplug everything you don't absolutely need and try again.

Comment: There is nothing connected to the computer except keyboard, mouse and monitor. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have searched on internet and found that the error code 0x8007000D was got by the user in case he download the corrupted package or any software and then if he wanted to install that particular download then the system show this type of error. So, the single solution about this problem is to again download the whole package and then try to install again that particular package.

Answer (score 0):

Umm... Lets see. So, since you want a dual boot you can't just run the setup from within XP. If you do that, it will only install with default settings and will over write your Windows XP. What you have to do is:

1. Redownload ur iso to remove the corruption error.
2. burn it onto a CD.
3. restart your computer and press F8 to enter the BIOS.
4. Under the Boot options, set XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX- DVD DRIVE as your first option.(X's stand for the serial number or model number of your drive..eg. Western Digital starts with WDC)
5. Then, Save with your changes.
6. It will reboot and you will see the DVD boot menu for the installation of Windows 7.

Have fun.